# Transformation accuracy MAGNA_To_WGS_1984_1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, wgs84

I am very new to ArcMap and GIS data in general and I have encountered the following problem. I am using two different sources of geospatial data on Colombia with one using GCS_MAGNA and the other using GCS_WGS_1984. As MAGNA_To_WGS_1984_1 is seemingly the only readily available transformation, I am using it for this purpose. Some features are contained in both data sources which allows me to assess the accuracy of the transformation (which according to the documentation should be 1 metre). However, in some instances the deviation between my data sources is more than 500m. Can anyone think of any other reason for such large deviations aside from errors in the underlying data?

Answer (score 0):

That transformation assumes that MAGNA (aka MAGNA-SIRGAS) and WGS 1984 are equivalent within 1 m accuracy. The parameters are zeroes, so only tiny changes in the latitude values due to the different ellipsoids would occur. Differences of greater than 500 m are not due to the differences in the geographic coordinate reference systems.

You're more likely looking at data issues--DMS or degrees-decimal minutes versus decimal degrees or something like that.